# Reproducing Holt-Winters analysis in the Cowpertwait-Metcalfe book

Tags: time-series, smoothing

I am having trouble reproducing some output for some R code in the time series book by Cowpertwait and Metcalfe.  There are quite a few typos in their code throughout the book, but in other cases I was able to reproduce what they say I should get by fixing the typos.  However, in their section on the Holt-Winters method, I am unable to do so.  Here is the code I used:

```
 wine.dat <- read.table("http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/andrew.metcalfe/Data/wine.dat", header = T); attach(wine.dat)
sweetw.ts <- ts(sweetw, frequency=12, start=c(1980,1))
sweetw.hw <- HoltWinters(sweetw.ts, seasonal="mult")
print(sweetw.hw)
```

The authors write that the estimates for the smoothing parameters from this code should be $\alpha = 0.4107$, $\beta = 0.0001516$, and $\gamma = 0.4695$.  The code above instead gave me $\alpha=0.4086698$ and $\gamma=0.4929402$ and a $\beta$ parameter exactly equal to 0.

I plotted the time series and it seems to exactly match the picture in the book, so I don't think the data file was changed after the book was published.  All I can guess is that my computer is using a different precision.

Comment: Can you quantify “slightly different” ? This could be due to optimization routine used in the book to be different from the HoltWinters function in R.

Comment: I updated the OP with the exact $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ values I got.

Comment: I reran the HW method with the parameters set equal to the ones given in the book, and SSE was larger than when I ran it with no parameter values.  That makes me think it is not a problem of precision but is either a difference in the data or in the algorithm implementation itself.  Is that a reasonable conclusion?

Comment: Possibly due to different optimization settings in different versions of R. I'm guessing that you are running a different version of R from what they used in their book.